# MYSQL delete from large table increase the delete time for each transaction

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to delete data from table which contains almost 6,000,000,000 records , with where clause.

here is the stored procedure I am using and running from command prompt MySQL in windows.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `clean_table`( )
BEGIN   
    REPEAT
        DO SLEEP(1);
        DELETE FROM tablename
        WHERE exportInfoId<=8479  limit 100000;   
        SELECT ROW_COUNT();
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Its deleting the data but it continue incasing the time for each delete transaction. **Why its keep increasing , even when with delete the earlier transaction reduce the data in table  ?   Is there any way to make it same time for each transaction ?**  I am already using sleep as suggested in some other answers .

[image]

Comment: Does the column `exportInfoId` is indexed (alone or as some index prefix)? if not then this is a norma - the server needs to scan more data until 100k rows matched the condition is found.

Comment: No there is no index on that column and I didn't understand why that time continue increasing , even with delete earlier  transaction , the data is reducing . Its firs time 1 min and 4the time its 11 mins ?

Comment: Imagine that each second row matches. First execution. The server scans 200k rows (the rows are scanned in the cluster index ordering), finds 100k rows to be deleted and deletes them. Second execution. The server scans 300k rows (it must start from the same beginning) until it finds 100k rows to be deleted (and skips 100k non-used entries) and deletes them. Each execution the amount of rows to be scanned (and non-used entries to be skipped) increases. Of course the execution time increases too. Get the query statistic after each query (SHOW PROFILE) - you must see the reads amount increasing.

Comment: Are you deleting a great majority of the rows in the table? It might be quicker to copy the rows you want to keep to a second table, and once that's done, then swap the table names.

Comment: @BillKarwin  will it be fast in case there is no index on table ? for example  insert into copytable select from main_table where exportinfoid > 7456;  but no index on exportinfoid .

Comment: If there's no index, it will have to do a table-scan, but if you only need a small set of rows, you could copy them it in one table-scan instead of many table-scans as you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an index to the column with which you are using to find the record(s) to be deleted.

With an index, MySQL knows exactly where the records are to be found so it can go straight to the record(s).

Without an index, then the table must be searched row by row.

The difference is, without an index the deletes are performed in the order of the primary key however, with an index the records will be searched in the order of that particular column.

To add an index, do what @o-jones points out below in the comments, which is:

```
// Normal Index
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX exportInfoId (exportInfoId);

// Reverse Index
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX exportInfoId (exportInfoId DESC);
```

Adding an index to the column is the correct answer here however, there may be other answers that work for you, depending on your use-case.

Comment: Just curious to understand how much time it will take to add index on such large table ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to speculate on that right now.

Comment: You want the normal, not reverse, index. In recent MySQL versions you can add an index concurrently with a normal workload. It's pretty efficient. And, once you have the index, reduce your `LIMIT 100000` to a smaller number like `LIMIT 5000`. That will tie up your table for less time for each batch of rows.

Comment: @AlexAnder - I agree that an index is the logical answer, but, depending on the data distribution, it may not be the "best" answer.  (See my Answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, adding an index would help a lot.  ("DESC" is optional.)

Sure it will take time to add an index to 6B rows.  Newer versions of MySQL can do it "instantly", but that just means it is happening in the background and is not available for a long time.

The reason for the slowdown is that the `DELETEs` are skipping over more and more rows that are not to be deleted.  The `INDEX` would avoid that.  (As Akina described.)

A note about `DELETE` (and `UPDATE`):  It is slow because it keeps the deleted rows in case of a `ROLLBACK` (which would happen after a power failure).

There are other techniques.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig .  The main one that comes to mind for your task is to walk through the table 1K rows at a time based on the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Note that this avoids *repeatedly* skipping over rejected rows.)

If "most" of the table is to be deleted, copying the table over is the best way.  (See that link.)  Note also that the table will not shrink after `DELETEs`; the freed up space will be reused, to some extent.  (As Bill Commented on.)

If you are deleting "old" data such that `PARTITIONing` would work, then `DROP PARTITION` is virtually instantaneous on all versions (since 5.1?) of MySQL.  (That is also mentioned in my link.)  (Partitioning is usually used for "time-series"; does `exportInfoId` work like a "time"?)

To Alex, I say "there *may* be other answers".

As for 100K vs 5K rows; I like 1K because above that, you get into "diminishing returns".  And at 100K you might hit various buffer size settings that actually cause 100K to run *slower*.